# How to get speed of network, whether it is fast or slow in xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

How to get speed of network, whether it is fast or slow in xamarin iOS?
I used NetworkReachability, But it is giving result that url is reachable or not?
I want to get speed of network , fast or poor?` private static NetworkReachability _defaultRouteReachability;

```
    public static event EventHandler ReachabilityChanged;

    public static bool IsNetworkAvailable(string url)
    {
        if (_defaultRouteReachability == null)
        {
            _defaultRouteReachability = new NetworkReachability(url);
            _defaultRouteReachability.SetNotification(OnChange);
            _defaultRouteReachability.Schedule(CFRunLoop.Current, CFRunLoop.ModeDefault);
        }

        NetworkReachabilityFlags flags;

        return _defaultRouteReachability.TryGetFlags(out flags) &&
            IsReachableWithoutRequiringConnection(flags);
    }

    private static bool IsReachableWithoutRequiringConnection(NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
    {
        // Is it reachable with the current network configuration?
        bool isReachable = (flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable) != 0;

        // Do we need a connection to reach it?
        bool noConnectionRequired = (flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.ConnectionRequired) == 0;

        // Since the network stack will automatically try to get the WAN up,
        // probe that
        if ((flags & NetworkReachabilityFlags.IsWWAN) != 0)
            noConnectionRequired = true;

        return isReachable && noConnectionRequired;
    }

    private static void OnChange(NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
    {
        var h = ReachabilityChanged;
        if (h != null)
            h(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }`
```

Comment: ISPs and hosting companies usually provide a looking glass server, where you're free to download files on specific sizes. That should help to figure the approximate real network speed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample. I am not understanding this solution.

Comment: Like, just [download the file and time it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29152636/529282), if google.com is too small to check, find an actual looking glass server or find bigger webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can help you, unless you want to use a library. This basically gives you the technical definition of internet speed, but the real number will be a little bigger. It's very similar to the solution suggested by @Martheen

```
public async Task<string> CheckInternetSpeed()
{
    //DateTime Variable To Store Download Start Time.
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
    string internetSpeed;
    try
    {
        // Create Object Of WebClient
        var client = new HttpClient();
        //Number Of Bytes Downloaded Are Stored In ‘data’
        byte[] data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://www.example.com/");
        //DateTime Variable To Store Download End Time.
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
        //To Calculate Speed in Kb Divide Value Of data by 1024 And Then by End Time Subtract Start Time To Know Download Per Second.
        Console.WriteLine("ConnectionSpeed: DataSize (kb) " + data.Length / 1024);
        Console.WriteLine("ConnectionSpeed: ElapsedTime (secs) " + (dt2 - dt1).TotalSeconds);
        internetSpeed = "ConnectionSpeed: (kb/s) " + Math.Round((data.Length / 1024) / (dt2 - dt1).TotalSeconds, 2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        internetSpeed = "ConnectionSpeed:Unknown Exception-" + ex.Message;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(internetSpeed);
    return internetSpeed;
}
```

Xamarin Essentials library can't get you Internet speed, but if you use dependency injection, you can use the native api s like [this](https://gist.github.com/alexrainman/1566aa6592549cbf0102).